# how to design this edit-icon?

Tags: html, css

Please check and run this example.

```css
img {
  width: 10px;
}

pre {
  overflow: initial;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <pre>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur ad<img src="https://randomm.cdn.bcebos.com/edit%20(1).svg"></img></pre>
  
  <pre>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetu<img src="https://randomm.cdn.bcebos.com/edit%20(1).svg"></img></pre>
  
   <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod voluptate nesciunt velit? Officiis doloribus fugit et harum nobis assumenda<img src="https://randomm.cdn.bcebos.com/edit%20(1).svg"></img></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to let the icon follow the text inside the `pre` tag, but at some situation the text length will be exact the max-width of the `pre` tag, which leads to make the icon present at the next line.This has a very bad user experience. Please tell me how to design this edit-icon. Thank you.

Comment: You can edit-icon set on top right with help of **position: absolute** and define right padding inside **pre** tag

Comment: @RaeeshAlam Thanks for ur help. But in this way, how can i let the icon follow the text inside the pre tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it. It's a staic image.

Solution: You can use Icon from https://fontawesome.com/icons

Steps:

1. Add a font awesome CDN.
2. Stats using icons
3. You can easily design icons using CSS

Example:

```
<i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
```